# How-To: wpdb Insert Record With Date

Tags: wpdb

I am writing a plugin where I need to pre-load some data in the custom tables that I create upon Activation.  My inserts have run fine thus far until I attempt to insert a record with a DATE datatype.  Can someone please tell me what I have wrong here?

Database Table Definition:

```
$sql =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix.SSM_ACADEMIC_YEAR_TABLE. " (
                  id mediumint(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  academicyear VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                  begin_date date NOT NULL,
                  end_date date NOT NULL,
                  created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                PRIMARY KEY (id));";

    $wpdb->query($sql);
```

Database Insert:

```
$current_year = array(
            'academicyear' => '2012 - 2013',
            'begin_date'   => date('Y-m-d', '2012-08-14'),
            'end-date'     => date('Y-m-d', '2013-05-31')
        );

        $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.SSM_ACADEMIC_YEAR_TABLE, $current_year);
```

I have tried many different methods like just using => '2012-08-14' but that doesn't work either.  I'm sure there's some syntax I am either missing or I have wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) does not take a human readable string. It takes a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You need to convert that human date to a timestamp with [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
'begin_date'   => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-08-14')),
```

Of course, there is really no need to convert a YEAR-MONTH-DAY date into a timestamp only to convert it back that a YEAR-MONTH-DAY format.

Comment: There is a typo in your code. You created `end_date` but are inserting data into `end-date`. I am marking this for closing as 'too localized' but you could just delete it.

Comment: OMG!  Thanks so much! That was it and yes, I will delete it.

Comment: apparently I don't have the cred enough to delete it, so you can close it.

Comment: for others looking at this, there's no need to make strtotime of `2012-08-14` and then generate the same again with `date` - just `'begin_date' => '2012-08-14'` is fine

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the function `current_time`. For example:

```
<?php $time = current_time( 'mysql' ); ?>
```

The function will return the date-time string that mysql requires.

You can find more details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time). And if you are interested in  “time zone programming problems”, you would like to read this article ***[Managing times & dates in WordPress](https://crowdfavorite.com/managing-times-and-dates-in-wordpress/)***.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct. You can pass string date formats to database, as long as they are formated in a manner that database understands (e.g. `2022-01-15T20:34:34` or `2022-01-15 20:34:34`). You can find [mariadb specifications here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datetime/), I am pretty sure they are the same as for MySQL.